# why do i get org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6049: Attempted a bean operation on a null object

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I get `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6049: Attempted a bean operation on a null object` when i click the submit button and the request goes to the following jsp:

```
<jsp:useBean id="namebean" class="BeanTesters.Bean">
        <jsp:setProperty name="namebean" property="name" param="Name" />
    </jsp:useBean>

    <%--Now check if the text-field data has been stored--%>
    <jsp:getProperty name="beanname" property="name" />
```

HTML code :

```
<form method="get" action="straighttojsp.jsp">
        <input type="text" name="Name" /> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit data"/>
    </form>
```

Bean class :

```
package BeanTesters;

public class Bean {

private String name = null;

public void setName(String n) {
    name = n;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;        
 }
}
```

Why do i get this exception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting property in bean `namebean` and trying to retrieve it back from bean `beanname`, which apparently is `null`